# Request & Response Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I need to send request to server appending xml data as below to the url of the server

```
<User>
<MobileNumber>xxxxxxxxxx</MobileNumber>
<UserAgent>yyyyy</UserAgent>
</User>
```

I will get back response as follows

```
<User>
<MobileNumber>xxxxxxxxxx</MobileNumber>
<ModelId>zzzzzz</ModelId>
<AuthKey>aaaaaaaaa</AuthKey>
<UserAgent>yyyyy</UserAgent>
</User>
```

I want to parse the recieved xml data
What is the proper way to do this in Windows Phone(7)? first request the url with xml and then receive xml
I am new to windows phone development
what classes should be used??

I am very confused in -
WebClient
WebRequest
WebResponse
HttpWebRequest
HttpWebResponse

Edit: I tried the following code to send request, how do I receive the response??

```
private void Upload()
    {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var uri = new Uri("xxxxxxxxxx", UriKind.Absolute);
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "MobileNumber", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("yyyyyyyyy"));
        postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "UserAgent", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("WP7"));

        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();
        webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
        webClient.UploadProgressChanged += webClient_UploadProgressChanged;
        webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Is this tutorial from the [Nokia Developer Wiki](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Employees_app_with_XML_parsing_and_messaging_in_WP7) any use?

Comment: I saw that wiki many times before also.
It is mostly about parsing xml data
I am having problem in receiving the xml data
I need to fetch the xml data before I can parse it
How do I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps

Step 1: add the namespace    `using System.Net;`

Step 2:

```
public void Upload() 
{
WebRequest webRequest;
                webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url + Mobile_No + Request); 
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(newAsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);
}
```

Step 3:

```
public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
                webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
                string postData = "Test";
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                postStream.Close();
                webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
            }
```

Step 4 :

```
public void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response;
                response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamResponse.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                response.Close();
                if (Response == "")
                {
                   //show some error msg to the user                    

                }
                else
                {                   
                  //Your response will be available in "Response"                        
                }
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                //error    
            }
        }
```

Check this now

Comment: I dont understand this part
"webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url + Mobile_No + Request);"
url is type Url/Uri
Mobile_no, Request should be xml data???
How do I create the correct url???

Comment: after finding out the correct terminology,
I need to POST the data in the xml above.
Do i need to write it here : "string postData = "Test";" ??
And again
I just need to write the url here right??? ; "webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url + Mobile_No + Request);"
@Vijay.P

Comment: "Url + Mobile_No + Request" is meant for sample format. You can parse any data inside this, which will give you a response.Give your request URL with XML data (which has mobile number and useragent).

Comment: I tried Your code as follows : 
string postData = "<User><MobileNumber>919958003450</MobileNumber><UserAgent>PC-Web-browser</UserAgent></User>";
And to check what response i am getting, i tried this : 
//Your response will be available in "Response" ChangeMyText(Response);
AND
void ChangeMyText(string mine)
        {
            Mytext.Text = mine;
        }
Where Mytext is a textblock - i got system.unauthorizedaccessexception error with textblock
T_T I am not understanding the concepts correctly
Thank you for your help
@Vijay.P

Comment: Also, how do I use the Response?? @Vijay.P

Comment: Thank You @Vijay.P
It finally worked
I set the output to show on the debug screen and found my mistake