# Build a Windows phone chat app with Post and Get request

Tags: post, windows-phone-8, get, request, chat

I am supposed to create a simple chat app using httppost and get in order to send message and to get message.

This is what I am supposed to get after sending the request to the API:

```
{"conversation":
    {"id":35,"created_at":"2014-11-16T19:21:11.000+01:00",
        "updated_at":"2014-11-16T19:21:11.000+01:00",
        "conversation_type":null,"option_id":null,
        "messages":[
            {"body":"lol","created_at":"2014-11-16T19:21:13.000+01:00","user_id":34},
            {"body":"payday","created_at":"2014-11-16T19:25:57.000+01:00","user_id":34},
            {"body":"lol","created_at":"2014-11-16T20:19:26.000+01:00","user_id":34},
            {"body":"izi","created_at":"2014-11-17T01:09:36.000+01:00","user_id":34},
            {"body":"LOWL","created_at":"2014-11-17T01:11:34.000+01:00","user_id":34}
        ],
        "users":[
            {"id":34,"email":"zegfault42@gmail.com","first_name":"Hugo","name":"Barbier"},
            {"id":36,"email":"ismael.bourg@gmail.com","first_name":"Ismael","name":"Bourg"}
        ]
    }
}
```

And I am supposed to make a post request in order to reply message. I just want to know what I can do and how I can design it.

Comment: Hi Patrice, welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question looks like a homework assignment. Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then try to fix your question so it fulfills the standards of SO more. Especially you should show your own effort - what you have serached for and it has not worked, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please read more about HTTP Post & Get methods, REST services.
It is very simple. You can find it on the internet.

Also, I had similar questions when I started developing.

Check the answer to my question here-

[Request & Response Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058974/request-response-windows-phone)

Hope this helps